# pygame window takes forever to start

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm following the alien invasion project from python crash course, at the beginning the book teaches how to open a simple window with a specific background color. I literally copy-pasted the code from the book and it still does not work.

```
import pygame
import sys

from settings import Settings

def run_game():
    # Initialize game and create a screen object.
    

    pygame.init()
    # Init settings
    my_settings = Settings()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((my_settings.screen_widht, my_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        screen.fill(my_settings.bg_color)
        
        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()
        
run_game()
```

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not saying the code doesn't work, it works without errors but takes a minute to open... it's something with my system, but I don't know what it is, that's why I'm asking

Edit2: I realized that if I remove pygame.init() the window opens instantly, not sure what it means

Comment: Can't reproduce with window size 1080p and background color white. Maybe the `Settings` object initialisation is slow?

Comment: Besides the error ```my_settings.screen_widht``` that should be  ```my_settings.screen_width``` the  window opened inmidiately. Try to change settings and lower the values of width and height and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible. The problem is with your system not with your code.

Comment: I am the author of Python Crash Course. This code is from the first edition of the book, which has been out of print since 2019. That's not the reason for the behavior you're seeing, but I highly recommend you work from a newer edition of the book. The rest of the projects in the first edition are even more outdated than this one at this point.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yeah that's what I thought, any ideas on what the problem would be?
I tried adjusting settings but it's still not opening instantly, still 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) initializes all pygame modules. This may take some time on some systems. If you don't need all pygame modules, just leave it out. For the display and event handling it is not necessary to call `pygame.init()` at all. If you need other modules, you can itialize them separately (e.g. `pygame.font.init()`, `pygame.mixer.init()`).

See [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)

> Initialize all imported pygame modules. No exceptions will be raised if a module fails, but the total number if successful and failed inits will be returned as a tuple. You can always initialize individual modules manually, but pygame.init()initialize all imported pygame modules is a convenient way to get everything started. The init() functions for individual modules will raise exceptions when they fail.
>
> **You may want to initialize the different modules separately to speed up your program or to not use modules your game does not require.**

Comment: @EliasLP It is probably a problem with your system nit with your code. Possibly with one of your drivers. However, I can only guess. StackOverflow is for questions about the code, not the system.